# Direct injection of double values in a matrix using Spring Framework

Tags: java, xml, spring, matrix

I would like to know if there is any way to directly inject a set of double values in a matrix using the .xml configuration file and the Spring Framework.

More precisely, I have something like this:

```
public myClass {

    private double [][] myMatrix;

    ...

}
```

I would like to inject the values for each row and each column of myMatrix when defining the myMatrix property of the bean instantiated from myClass.

I solved the problem in this way, but isn't there any other (faster) solution?

```
        <property name="myMatrix">
            <array>
                <array>
                    <value>0.80</value>
                    <value>0.0</value>
                </array>
                <array>
                    <value>0.60</value>
                            <value>0.0</value>
                </array>
                <array>
                    <value>0.40</value>
                    <value>0.0</value>
                </array>
                <array>
                    <value>0.20</value>
                            <value>0</value>
                </array>
        </array>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Easy - setter or constructor injection.  But I doubt that this is something you'll want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Easy - setter or constructor injection.

But I doubt that this is something you'll want to do.

Are you just learning Spring?  I'm guessing yes, because enthusiasm can cause overuse.

I can see where you might have a `MatrixFactory` class that would be under Spring's control.  maybe you'd use it to create `Matrix` instances at runtime.

But it's more likely that you'll want to create several `Matrix` instances and manipulate them.  It's appropriate to call `new` in that case and not have them be controlled by Spring.

A real application will have a combination of objects that are managed by Spring and others that are created by the user and created by calling `new`.  Knowing when to apply each technique is important.